# Что такое нелинейная рекурсия?

Tags: рекурсия, терминология

Можете навести пример простой нелинейной рекурсии и объяснить в чём её суть?

Answer (score 1):

**Линейная** рекурсия - когда в рекурсивной функции вызывается только **один** экземпляр самой себя.

**Нелинейная** рекурсия - когда в теле рекурсивной ф-ции есть (как минимум) **два** вызова самой себя.

Допустим, мы ищем вхождение элемента в некоторое множество.

**Линейная** рекурсия - проверяем первый элемент множества и делаем **один** рекурсивный вызов на остаток множества.

**Нелинейная** рекурсия - разбиваем множество на две половинки и делаем **два** вызова самой себя для каждой половинки множества. И так, до тех пор, пока в множестве не останется один элемент.

Comment: О, когда я делал рекурсию для решения головоломки в одной игрушке, то это была нелинейная рекурсия :) https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dcc854881d24be835e3a9e81766ac33156ee0d9a/FFXIII-2_clock_puzzle_solver/main.py#L51 Полезный ответ :)

Comment: @Sergey Где Вы взяли такое определение нелинейной рекурсии?

Comment: @MBo  Это не определение. Это пояснение.

Comment: @Sergey Дело в том, что в более-менее серьёзных источниках однозначного толкования этого термина не видно.

Comment: @Sergey [режим-модератора-википедии] Без авторитетных источников это может сойти за оригинальное исследование и вообще выдумку термина) [/режим-модератора-википедии]

Comment: @andreymal *Без авторитетных источников* - цитата "Если же каждый экземпляр подпрограммы может вызвать себя несколько раз, то рекурсия называется нелинейной" НОУ "Интуит" можно считать авторитетным источником?

Comment: @andreymal *может сойти за оригинальное исследование* - исследования тут нет. Очень простое рассуждение: Если рекурсия линейна, то на первом шаге будет один экземпляр в стеке, на втором - два и т.д. Если рекурсия НЕлинейна (с коэффициентом == 2), то на первом шаге будет один элемент стека, на втором - три, на третьем - 7, на четвёртом - 15, на 5 - 45. Явно НЕлинейная зависимость.

Comment: «НОУ "Интуит" можно считать авторитетным источником?» — возможно)